# XamlReader.Load is throwing System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: c#, xaml, load, xamlreader

What could be wrong with the following:

```
<Run FontWeight=\"Bold\" Foreground=\"#FF0000FF\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xml:space=\"preserve\"><Run.TextDecorations><TextDecoration Location=\"Underline\" /></Run.TextDecorations>046/98 5802007513 \r</Run>
```

While similar others are loaded fine by the XamlReader.Load, this throws following exception:

> "A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line
>   1, position 233."

Code to replicate the issue:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace XamlTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String str = "<Run FontWeight=\"Bold\" Foreground=\"#FF0000FF\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xml:space=\"preserve\"><Run.TextDecorations><TextDecoration Location=\"Underline\" /></Run.TextDecorations>046/98 5802007513 \r</Run>";
            Stream s = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(str));
            try
            {
                var temp = XamlReader.Load(s);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling XamlReader.Parse instead of XamlReader.Load doesn't throw exception "XamlParseException" with the same input, however I don't know what's the difference and how it is working.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String str = "<Run FontWeight=\"Bold\" Foreground=\"#FF0000FF\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xml:space=\"preserve\"><Run.TextDecorations><TextDecoration Location=\"Underline\" /></Run.TextDecorations>046/98 5802007513 \r</Run>";

        try
        {
            var temp = XamlReader.Parse(str);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

use " (Double quote) instead of \ as show below

String str = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xml:space=""preserve"">046/98 5802007513 \r";

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with double quotes are a backslash! It didn't work.

Comment: try removing space from "98 5802007513"